# how to create image gallery with horizontal scroll

Tags: android, image, scroll, gallery, swap

How can I make an image gallery with horizontal scroll in android studio in which images can be displayed one image at the screen and with buttons on the right and the left for moving to other images

Comment: use `viewpager` for the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ViewPager` instead of `HorizontalScrollView`,

Please follow this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-image-slider-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use horizontal recycleview. Here's the code:

**fragment/activity layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       ...

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        />
            ...

</LinearLayout>
```

**item:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_item_view_image"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="109dp"
    android:layout_height="109dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter:**

```
public class HorizontalPhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalPhotosAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView riv;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            riv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_item_view_image);

        }
    }


    public HorizontalPhotosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList, String[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bitmapList = bitmapList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item_view, parent, false);

        if (itemView.getLayoutParams ().width == RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            itemView.getLayoutParams ().width = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.riv.setImageBitmap(bitmapList.get(position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bitmapList.size();
    }
}
```

**implementation in fragment/activity:**

```
            horizontalAdapter=new HorizontalPhotosAdapter(getContext(), bitmapList);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
            horizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
```